# Can someone please explain my VBScript error

Tags: vbscript

This script gives me a number between 1 and 3 and enters the corresponding letter(1=a,2=b,3=c). I have done this before and it works correctly in the letter sense. The InputBox gets a number higher than 0 and that's how many letters that it SHOULD allow the script to enter however my `do while max > count` isn't stopping it at the max. Just continuing forever until i disable it maually via task manager. Does anyone see anything wrong with this?

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

max = InputBox("Max number of characters (Numbers Only!)",  "Enter Integer")

If max = "" Then
    Wscript.Quit
ElseIf max < 0 Then
    Wscript.Quit
End If

count = 0
ws.Run "notepad.exe"
Wscript.sleep 1000

Do While max > count

    count = count + 1
    Randomize
    rand = Int((3 - 1 + 1) * rnd + 1)

    If rand = 1 Then
        char = "a"
    ElseIf rand = 2 Then
        char = "b"
    ElseIf rand = 3 Then
        char = "c"
    End If

    Wscript.sleep 50
    ws.Sendkeys char

Loop

Wscript.Quit
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `max` variable contains a string `"3"` instead of the raw numeric value `3`. VBScript's relative-comparison operators (`>`, `>`, `>=`, `<=`) for string values vs numbers don't work like they do in other languages (and they are not based off the ASCII value of the first character of the string either).

The fix is to use `CInt` to ensure that `max` is numeric:

```
Dim max
max = InputBox( ... )
If max = ""  Then ... End If
max = CInt( max )

Do While max > count
    ...
Loop
```

BTW, I would rename `count` to `i` to better convey its semantic-meaning.

Comment: thank you it is now working as wished. But could you clarify what you mean by `i` being better than `count`, what does it stand for?

Comment: `i` is usually used as name for a counter variable (often used as an array index or iterator, it's a nice coincidence those names start with `i` and `i` also happens to be the thinnest letter of the alphabet).

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification ( and im not a no lifer stalking my stackoverflow constanyly refreshing i just happened to see it when i came back to it XD

Answer (score 1):

[Comparison Operators (VBScript) reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.84).aspx): read how expressions are compared or what results from the comparison, depending on the underlying subtype:

> If one expression is numeric and the other is a string then the
>   numeric expression is less than the string expression.

I'd use next code snippet:

```
max = InputBox("Max number of characters (Numbers Only!)",  "Enter Integer")

If Not Isnumeric( max) Then  Wscript.Quit ''' affects `max = ""` as well
max = CInt( max)                          ''' convert `max` to a Variant of subtype Integer
If max < 0 Then Wscript.Quit
```

Read [Randomize Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38d7ckek(v=vs.84).aspx), [Rnd Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e566zd96(v=vs.84).aspx) and [Looping Through Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbe735w2(v=vs.84).aspx) as well. Maybe

```
Randomize
For count = 1 to max
    ''' more code here based on `count` value and `rnd()` function
Next
```

could be better (random seed) and simpler (loop) than

```
count=0
Do While max > count
    count = count + 1
    Randomize
    ''' more code here based on `count` value and `rnd()` function
Loop
```

Finally, read [bypassing the errant keystrokes complaint](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/automate-tasks-with-windows-script-hosts-sendkeys-method/):

> One of the biggest complaints I’ve heard about using the `SendKeys`
>   method for macros is that if the window focus somehow changes in the
>   middle of the script execution, the keystrokes will be sent to
>   whatever window receives the focus. Now the danger of this is that the
>   keystrokes intended for one window might have disastrous effects (like
>   causing the loss of data) when applied to another window.